# Https server with socket and express

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm using SSL to encrypt my backend but my current solution opens two ports, one for sockets and the other for express, any approach to start both on the same port like HTTP ?

```
const port=4000;
if(process.env.ENABLE_SSL=='true')
{
    ////two ports are open 8989,4000
    server = https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync("sslLocation/ssl.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("sslLocation/ssl.cert")
    },app).listen("8989", '0.0.0.0',function(){
        console.log('Express server listening to port 8989');
    });
    global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    app.listen(port);
}
else
{
////one port only
// start the server
server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`App is running at: localhost:${server.address().port}`);
});
global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
}
```

also running `app.listen(server)`  in the ssl section, i can't access the apis

Comment: how are you accessing the api

Comment: @NehaTawar api on 4000, sockets on 8989

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `app.listen`, since you've already passed it to the `createServer` instance.

Comment: @BenFortune requests doesn't work if i didn't call app.listen